# Defining a variable with comma (or any other separator) in its name?

Tags: syntax, core-language, variable

How can I define *Mathematica* variable/function with comma in it?

For example, define`L00,1` as a variable?

I plan to use `L00,1` as a variable as 00 and 1 have different meanings. Other examples are like `L01,1`, `L10,0`, etc. The purpose to comma is to separate meanings when others see it, otherwise `L001` will cause confusion. I also hope to avoid `l["00",1]` as a variable as the `" "` sign will cause confusion to users not familiar with mathematica interpreting it as string. Any symbol added to the variable that serves as a separator between 00 and 1 would be fine. For example `L00;1` or `L00_1`. But they do not work. The purpose is to inform my user (colleagues) in a reader-friendly way.

If the question is not meaningful please ignore it or inform me.

Comment: `Subscript[a, "00", 1] = 12`

Comment: `a["00",1]` avoids `Subscript`

Comment: How to just define `L00,1` as a variable?

Comment: It's not possible. Try `Symbol["L00,1"]` to see the error.

Comment: Why do you want to do this though? Is it just for formatting?

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer 00 and 1 has different meanings so i do not want to put them together like`L001`. Is there any way to mimic the comma or separation?

Comment: @kww and I have already shown you two ways to do it.

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer why in `a["00",1]` there is no paraenthesis of 1 but have for 00?

Comment: By parenthesis=(), do you really mean quotation marks=""? (pinging @MariusLadegårdMeyer)

Comment: kww, this is of course possible.  But to help others give you a useful answer, can you edit your question and provide some context about how you plan on using this symbol.  -1 until you edit your question.

Comment: I mean quotation marks=""

Comment: The purpose of such requirement is important, if only for formatting, you should adapt to things like  `a["00",1]` or `a["00"][1]` like MLM suggested

Comment: So I cannot define a variable as `a00,1 = 2` but have to use `a["00",1] =2`? Thanks

Comment: There's not much information; for example, how many possible L's are there?  L01 L02 L11 L33? is there any meaningful arithmetic that needs to be done on the first pair of numbers?  what about the second index?  Are there only a limited number of L's overall? For input, you're going to have to use something like `l["00",1]` and then format it as `L00,1` in the output, is that ok?

Comment: There will be many L. Yes, if the code can be implemented as `L00,1` or any symbol that serves as a separator between 00 and 1 would be fine. For example `L00;1` or `L00_1`. But they do not work.  `l["00",1]` would be good but i am afraid the user would interpret `" "` as string as they are not.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes if I can format it as `L00,1` in the output it will be great.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possibility:

```
MakeBoxes[l[a_, b_], form_] :=  RowBox[{"l", "[", 
  ToBoxes[PaddedForm[0, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]], ",", 
  ToBoxes[b], "]"}]
```

`l[00,1]` continues to display as `l[00,1]`.

Here is another possibility:

```
MakeBoxes[l[a_String, b_], form_] := 
  With[{string = "\"L" <> a <> "," <> ToString[b] <> "\""}, 
  InterpretationBox[string, l[a, b]]]
```

`l["00",1]` displays as `L00,1`

Comment: thank you very much, this was very useful for me, this is a vwonderfull forum.  thank you again

Answer (score 4):

As it has been pointed out in the comments made to your question, using reserved symbols in identifiers is not allowed. What you can and might want to do is bind expressions to values. The arguments of the expression can serve as indices or tags to produce the kind of differentiation you want.

Here are two examples of what I am alluding to.

```
a["00", 1] = 3; a["10", 0] = 42;
a["00", 1]^2 + a["10", 0]
```

> `51`

```
b[0, 1][x_] := 1 + Log10[x]; b[10, 0] = 42;
b[10, 0]^b[0, 1][2] // N
```

> `129.389`